# Save uint16 tiff image as truecolor with Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, export, tiff

I am processing microscopy images (in Matlab) in the tiff format, normally uint8 or uint16. Basically I read them, put them in a cell array for processing and then export them in the tiff format either as an image sequence or a stack (using imwrite and either the 'overwrite' or 'append' writemode property of imwrite, respectively). Up to now everything works very well.

The problem I'm having is the following:

When I open the images with ImageJ, they are not in truecolor "RGB" color mode, but rather in composite mode. For example ImageJ reads the data as 8 bit, which it is, but does not open the image as a truecolor (Sorry for the bad choice of words I don't know the right terminology). Hence I have to manually combine the 3 channels together, which is bothersome for large datasets.

Here is a screen shot explaining. On the left is what I would like,i.e. what I obtain if I open the image directly with ImageJ, and on the right is what I currently have after saving images with Matlab and opening them with ImageJ, which I don't want.

[image]

The code I'm using to export the image sequence is the following. "FinalSequenceToExport" is the cell array containing the images.

```
for i = 1:SliceNumber
    ExportedName = sprintf('%s%s%d.tiff',fileName,'Z',i);
  imwrite(FinalSequenceToExport{i},ExportedName,'tif','WriteMode','overwrite','Compression','none');

end
```

- If I ask Matlab the size of FinalSequenceToExport{1}, for instance, it gives 512 x 512 x 3.
- If I open a given image in the command window and then save it with the same code as above, it does what I want and the resulting image opens as I want in ImageJ. Hence my guess would be that the problem arises from the use of the cell array but I don't understand how.

I hope I've been clear enough. If not please ask for more details.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you upload a sample bad image somewhere. Or maybe create it with dummy data? (RGB = uint8(rand(20,30,3)*100)) and confirm that image j sees it as a non standard RGB image? On my machine imwrite(uint8(rand(10,10,3)),'/tmp/t','tif','WriteMode','overwrite','Compression','none'); results in ImageJ reading it like a normal RGB. While imwrite(uint16(rand(10,10,3)),'/tmp/t','tif','WriteMode','overwrite','Compression','none'); results in the three slice view you seem to be talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yes it works if I add imwrite(uint8(FinalSequenceToExport{i}),...). However the image is quite saturated it might be because I used imadjust when importing the data. Thanks! You can post an answer so I can accept it if you want.

Comment: When I do what Ashish did ("imwrite(uint16(...") I get not exactly what you got ("1/3 Red, .., 16-bit" instead of "8 bit"). So something might still be different. However I guess by only saving uint8 one can circumvent the whole thing. ImageJ seem to only process RGB as 8-bit [color images](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-9.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link/comment @ Trilarion I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting this question I found the following to work, thanks to the hint from @Ashish:

```
imwrite(uint8(FinalSequenceToExport{i}/255),...);
```

I just needed to divide by 255 after converting to uint8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the the 'ColorSpace'

Try this

```
imwrite(FinalSequenceToExport{i},ExportedName,...
       'tif','WriteMode','overwrite','Compression','none', ...
       'ColorSpace', 'rgb');
```

Comment: thanks for the hint! However it produces the same result as before.